# android emulator copy files in system partition

Tags: android, copy, system, emulation

I need to copy files to the system partition of the emulator. As it is read only by default, I use the command "adb remount" to have write permissions and I can then copy the files.
My problem is that when I close the emulator and that I restart it, the copied files were missing. It's very annoying because I must write file permissions that are read at startup of the emulator (platform.xml file in /system/etc/permissions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to add those files to the firmware that was used to create the emulator image.

Comment: but maybe it is possible to force the emulator read the files located in /etc/permissions without a reboot?

Comment: I've never created firmware, so I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

The system partition you saw is only a tmp file which will be created during each execution is the reason why you will lose all your files.

The emulator will copy the system.img to the tmp file (something like /tmp/emulator-dDiaPX). All your modifications are made there. So it is easy to understand why all your files are gone, since they have never appeared in the real system.img.
In order to see the opened files, You can use:

`lsof -p pid-of-emulator`

The right method to do so is to place your files at the directory /data/ or /sdcard/.