# Android : Read-only file system

Tags: android, terminal, sh

I'm using a terminal emulator on Android 4.1.1 device.

When I run `cat > sample`, it says: `Can't create sample: Read-only file system.`

I don't want to root my device.

Any workarounds?

Comment: / is read only. only /mnt/sdcard is writable by users

Comment: @blackbelt Care to post this as an answer so the question does not keep floating around unanswered?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, your system partition (mounted as /) is read-only. And you can remount it as read-write. However, all the files your modified to the system partition will not survive when you restart your emulator. You can refer more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237190/android-emulator-copy-files-in-system-partition/20963355#20963355).

A correct way is to deploy your files at /data/ or /sdcard/.